# Segundo, minutos entre el guardado y la hora actual

Tags: php, mysql

Hola un cordial saludos,

tengo un inconveniente al momento de consultar quiero tener lo que es el intervalo desde que se realizo el guardo en la base de datos hasta el momento que refresca la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una tabla que me guarda el registro de la fecha y hora.

Quiero algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento tengo de codigo:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` ORDER BY `records`.`modificado` DESC
```

Que me arroja lo que son los ultimos registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He realizado un pequeño test para lo que necesitas.
No tomes en cuenta la creación de la tabla y la inserción.

Lo que hice fue insertar datos de tiempo en una tabla. Después de eso aplicar la siguiente lógica para tener un tiempo de diferencia entre el valor en el que se guardo y el valor de la fecha actual. Entonces obtienes el valor de tiempo que ha pasado desde que se guardo el registro.

1. Con TIMESTAMPDIFF obtienes la diferencia entre las fechas que deseas, en este caso la fecha del registro y la fecha actual del sistema.
2. Con SEC_TO_TIME obtienes esa información en segundos, prácticamente como un cronometro en formato (hora:min:seg). Ejemplo (00:02:04)

```
///Creación de tabla
create table dates(
    id int auto_increment,
    datetimeInit datetime,
    primary key(id)
);

///Inserción de datos
insert into test.dates values(1, NOW());
insert into test.dates values(2, NOW());


///Sacar diferencia de tiempos
SELECT datetimeInit, now() as horaActual, 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, datetimeInit, now())) as secondsDiff
FROM dates;
```

Estos son los resultados obtenidos con la query:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya solo tendrías que adaptar las sentencias `SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, datetimeInit, now()))` a tu problema.

Espero esto te sea de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Wow tuve que agregarle algunas cositas pero si funciono a la perfeccion muy agradecido